# Calculate DOB from a given string format

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Following is the date time I have. I need to calculate the age (in years ) and the days of a given date of birth.

The format of the Date of Birth is given below

```
Thu Jul 13 2021 19:10:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Code

```
CalculateAge (dob :string) : string {

    if (dob === null) return "age";


    let [year, month, day] = dob.split('-').map(Number);

    month -=1;
    const ag = Date.now() - new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
    const ad = new Date(ag); 
    return Math.abs(ad.getUTCFullYear() - 1970).toString();
```

}

The output I get is NaN. How can I solve this by getting the correct DOB from a date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to convert date string to yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
convertDateString(str :string) : string {
  let date = new Date(str);
  mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
}
console.log(convertDateString("Thu Jul 13 2021 19:10:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))
//-> "2021-07-13"
```

You can use below function to calculate Age

```
calculateAge() {
    let birthday = convertDateString("Thu Jul 13 2021 19:10:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
    let ageDifferentMs = Date.now() - new Date(birthday).getTime();
    let ageDate = new Date(ageDifferentMs ); // epoch miliseconds
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```